# making a router, need help figuring out why I get 403

Tags: php

Sorry I couldn't figure out a better short explaining title

I have this simple router for small site im making.

if there is a dot in the request_uri, it will exit, for stopping breakout. but when i try an url, i get 403 on my own server

Why do a get 403? my strpos should catch this

```
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$params = explode('/', $request);

if (strpos($request, '.') !== false) {
//breakout attempt
}

if (!file_exists(sprintf('pages/%s.php', $params[1]))) {
//requested page does not exists, throw or display error
    error();
} else {
    include sprintf('pages/%s.php', $params[1]);
}
```

Now this catches urls like

```
http://localhost/asfasg/asfass.sg
http://localhost/www.hello.se
http://localhost/asfasg/dsgsdg/fas.asgas
```

but

```
http://localhost/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1w87N9MLhM
http://localhost/banana://ww.sdf.xx/saf
```

it seems like if it has `something:` in request uri

```
You don't have permission to access /https://www.youtube.com/watch on this server.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/7.0.2RC1 Server at localhost Port 80
```

Why?

Comment: Value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`?

Comment: Are you sure the request is being sent to your router and not straight to the requested resource?

Comment: If you're using apache's mod_rewrite, then I'd suspect that your RerouteRule regex isn't catching some special characters like `:` and those requests are going through as normal. If this is the problem then you should change your rule to `RewriteRule .* router.php [QSA]`

Answer (score 0):

```
$request = "http://localhost/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1w87N9MLhM";
$params = explode('/', $request);

//you want the last index which should be the filename
$filename = array_pop($params);

if (strpos($filename, '.') !== false) {
//breakout attempt
}

if (!file_exists(sprintf('pages/%s.php', $filename))) {
//requested page does not exists, throw or display error
    error();
} else {
    include sprintf('pages/%s.php', $filename);
}
```